# Passing const char* to function from external library that takes a char*

Tags: c++, c, char, constants, dlsym

Consider I have the following function in a dynamic external library `libExternal.dylib`:

```
void print(char* str)
{
    // Changes the first char to 'a' and prints the string
    *str = 'a';
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Next, I have an executable that loads this external library and calls the function (error checking omitted):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    void* hLib = dlopen("libExternal.dylib", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL);

    typedef void(*printFunc)(const char*);
    printFunc func = (printFunc)dlsym(hLib, "print");

    std::string test = "hello";
    func(test.c_str());

    dlclose(hLib);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the function defined in the library takes a `char*` as parameter. When using `dlsym`, I made it get a function that takes a `const char*`. And it works!

My question is, how is this possible? The dynamic loader ignores const types? I really couldn't find an answer anywhere, so please help me! :)

**EDIT:**
I know this code is wrong, I'm just trying to understand how is this possible.

Comment: Please pay attention to the "Question preview" window and use proper code formatting (fixed it for you this time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works but it doesn't mean it's correct.

It doesn't ignore const types, you're casting the external function to a function which accepts const types:

```
typedef void(*printFunc)(const char*);
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^

printFunc func = (printFunc)dlsym(hLib, "print");
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And try to use right function signature to avoid ***undefined behavior*** due to modifying a const value.

Comment: That's correct, I'm casting it, but casting a const char* to char* is wrong. I don't understand how this code runs without crashing.

Comment: @LuísMendes it's a fluke that it's working. The dynamic storage of `std::string` is actually a non-`const` array so it appears to work fine. You're crossing a dynamic library boundary and using an incorrect function type; the compiler can't detect this mistake.

Comment: @Simple: `test` as a `std::string` is non-const, but the return value of `test.c_str()` is const.

Comment: @MM. right but that doesn't mean that the array `c_str` points to is actually `const`.

Comment: You can also take a pointer to an int, substract 5, set that and it doesn't crash. Doesn't mean that this is correct and will never crash. It's just a matter of luck.

Comment: @Simple: Yes.. but I think it's still an undefined behavior. In this case he's lucky but in general it can be a access violation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys! I know this code is wrong, I was just trying to understand how it was possible. Your contributions were really helpful.

Comment: @MM. it is undefined behaviour you're right. Was just pointing out one of the reasons it appears to work (the biggest problem is the incorrect function type).

Answer (score 1):

Passing `const char *` to `foo(char *str)` is undefined behavior (UB).

It could work, it might not.  It certainly will not work on systems that prevent writing to `const` memory.  Other systems are lenient and subsequent operations may / may not work as expected.

C11 draft 6.7.3. 6

Comment: @Giorgi Yes - it is still UB.  Think of a system where `const` and non-`const` pointers had some attribute attached to their pointer value.  And that system had no means to convert a `const` to non-`const` pointers.

Comment: @Giorgi Perhaps C11dr §6.3.2.3 8 "... If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @Giorgi Yes passing non-`const` to `const if fine.

Comment: @Giorgi "compatible" is not the same as "allow-ability"  `A` may be a subset of `B` even if `B` is not a subset of `A`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84510/discussion-between-chux-and-giorgi).

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        char a[] = "foo";
        const char *b = a;
        char *c = (char *)b;
        *c = 'a';
        printf("%s\n", b);
        return 0;
}
```

That's on a high level equivalent to what you're doing internally. Theoretically `char *c = (char *)b; *c = 'a';` is illegal, but in practice it happens to work in this particular case.

See `const` as a kind of contract between the writer of the API and the user of that API rather than something that is strictly enforced by the compiler and runtime. A secondary reason for const to exist is that it allows string literals to be put into read-only segments in programs opening up for many useful optimizations (like deduplication of strings), but I'd argue that primarily const is a just reminder for the programmer.

This is why in large projects I've seen adding const to function arguments is sometimes called "const poisoning". You poison some string or struct that is being passed around many different layers of APIs to make a promise that it isn't modified anywhere through the layers. The act of adding const by itself is very valuable to discover where unintended modifications happen. You can always get rid of the const quite easily and break the contract, but by not doing that you make it easier to read and debug your program. I've even done some experiments and compilers don't do optimizations that would be reasonable to do if the compiler expected const to be respected.

Sometimes it's even necessary to cast away const for completely legitimate reasons. For example when you have something like this:

```
struct foo {
    const char *string;
    int dynamic;
};
void
foo_dynamic(struct foo *f, int x)
{
    f->dynamic = 1;
    f->string = malloc(16);
    snprintf(&s->string, 16, "%d", x);
}
void
foo_static(struct foo *f, const char *x)
{
    f->dynamic = 0;
    f->string = x;
}
void
foo_free(struct foo *f)
{
    if (f->dynamic)
        free((void *)f->string);
    free(f);
}
```

In this case we make the promise in our API that we won't change the contents of what `foo->string` points to during the life time of `foo`, but we still need to be able to free it if we allocated it ourselves. A language <strike>fundamentalist</strike>lawyer might say that this is undefined behavior (it is) and there are solutions to achieve the same thing (there are), but this is pretty common in practice.